# Nginx configuration for MVC as client

Tags: model-view-controller, nginx, provider

Can somebody shine a light?
This is the issue: I need to create a site on a server that runs Nginx. I have no experience with this server, so I have been sticking my nose in it.
I want to omit the index.php, so that

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/welcome/index
```

becomes

```
http://www.mydomain.com/welcome/index
```

I then want to extract the /welcome/index so I can start and play with that in the MVC application. I have been looking around, but I get lost in the club of people that are likely doing their own configurations.

My question is if I can influence the server response as a client, like it is done with Apache through the htaccess file, or do I need to involve the provider who is hosting the server? I have requested to alter the server for this, but the support I get is not very helpful.

I was able to simulate the required server response within the nginx.conf file. This tells me that it can be done. 
For those interested. Read the values on the url through $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

```
worker_processes  1;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;


           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        }

                include mime.types;


        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?uri=$uri&$args;
}
```

And then you access the URI with `$_GET['uri']` from your `index.php`. You should take a look at nginx's [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) documentation.

Or if you want to access it via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` do it like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

#### Edit:

A few things just looking at your server conf:

- You've already included mime.types in the `http` block, so there is no need to include them again in the `server` block
- Probably a good idea to move `root html;` and `index index.php...` up to your `server` block
- Definitely read through [these](https://calomel.org/nginx.html) sample configurations (everything explained in the comments), very good way to start getting the hang of nginx conf
- [Nginx website](http://wiki.nginx.org/Resources) has some really good resources

Comment: Thank you @Nathan.I will most certainly check out the sites and experiment more with the configuration.

Comment: Would you confirm the fact that the provider should implement this configuration for me, or is there a way to overrule the server much like it is done on an Apache environment with an htaccess file?

Comment: @Daniel, I haven't actually had any experience with providers offering nginx hosting. But the answer to overriding system config is [no](http://cwells.net/2012/03/27/why-doesnt-nginx-support-htaccess-files/). The rules I gave you are just a start, and you should definitely look at the [examples link](https://calomel.org/nginx.html) , learn from it, and try coming up with your own config. There can be [security vulnerabilities](http://bit.ly/U52y9I), so you need to understand everything your doing

Comment: and if you want to start managing your own configs, you'd might like to start looking at [iaas](http://bit.ly/U52S8l) providers instead, hope it helps and good luck :)

Comment: Additional info with regards to the provider. They have looked again into the issue and tell me that there can be no changes to the configuration due to the account being on a shared host. :(

Comment: @daniel yep that would usually be the case, so if you want to customise your conf definitely look into iaas like rackspace (which I use)

Comment: To elaborate slightly and without going too much in depth ..  Is Rackspace like a computer in the cloud where I install my own web server and hence also control my own configuration?

Comment: Yep! except its not a computer, its an instance within a chain of servers (racks) sort of like what you get if you install another operating system with vmware on your computer. You'll need to choose your os (I recommend linux) and setup your webserver via command line. Check out [this](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/debian-50-lenny-setup) link for instructions on setting up a debian linux server. It can be a real hassle to get the hang of it, but once you do, it's well worth it.

Comment: Ok.. I get it. Thanks, your tips are golden. See you another time wandering around. :) cheers!